# How to limit size of all elasticsearch logs in logs4j2.properties?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, log4j

I have default log4j2.properties configuration file and I would like to make the rotation based on file sizes. The maximum disk space for all logs should be 5GB. What is the easiest way to configure it? What lines exactly should I leave in this properties file? How the file should look like? Default file that I've got: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/main/distribution/src/config/log4j2.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use rolling file appender. You can find detailed example in below link

https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j2/log4j2-rollingfileappender-example/

Comment: appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5 is the number of max  log files in rotation?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).